# I keep getting random errors now and then when I run my program

Tags: java, jvm, runtime-error

I've never seen these kinda errors before, things like:

`FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP cannot get thread local storage, jvmtiError=JVMTI_ERROR_WRONG_PHASE(112)`

If I run my program again afterwards the error doesn't appear which is what I don't get. This error has appeared several times today and even in this most simplist code sample:

test.java

```
import java.io.File;

public class test {

    public test() {
        OpenFile opf = new OpenFile("test/data.txt");
        OpenFile opf2 = new OpenFile(new File("test/data.txt"));

        OpenFolder opfo = new OpenFolder("test");
        OpenFolder opfo2 = new OpenFolder(new File("test"));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new test();
    }

}
```

OpenFile.java

```
import java.io.File;

public class OpenFile {
    File openFile;

    public OpenFile(String filePath) {
        openFile(new File(filePath));
    }

    public OpenFile(File file) {
        openFile(file);
    }

    public void openFile(File file) {
        if(file.exists())
            System.out.println("Exists");
        else
            System.out.println("!Exists");
    }

}
```

OpenFolder

```
import java.io.File;

public class OpenFolder {

    public OpenFolder(String string) {

    }

    public OpenFolder(File file) {

    }

}
```

There is nothing in my program that would cause an error as far as I can see and I cannot duplicate the error, all I know is the error happens during runtime.

Comment: What version of java do you use to run that code?

Comment: Are you running in debug mode?

Comment: JDWP is the java debugger - maybe try turning off debugging at runtime (or maybe its configured incorrectly).

Comment: Java ver is 1.8 and yes, I'm running in debug, but even so, I don't see why an error would occur.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like JDWP agent bug (probably [JDK-6988950](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6988950)). Unfortunately it has been fixed in JDK 9 only. Try replacing `jdwp.dll` / `libjdwp.so`  with the one from [JDK 9 EA](https://jdk9.java.net/download/).

Comment: From a comment at the bottom of https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6988950, "Changed the bug priority to P2 as the plan is to backport it to the 8u40 that is already in RDP1 phase."

Comment: @mmesser314 Just for the official update, this was fixed in Java 8 build 42.